# How can I make redux dispatch an action as well as return a promise?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asynchronous, ecmascript-6, promise

Here is my function in songAction.js

```
export function createSong(title, url, token) {

    axios.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = token

    return function (dispatch) {
        axios.post('http://localhost:8080/api/song/create', {
            title,
            link: url

        })
        .then((response) => {
            console.log('the response was', response)
            if(response.data.success){
                dispatch({type: "CREATE_SONG_FULFILLED", payload: response.data.song})
            } else {
                dispatch({type: "CREATE_SONG_REJECTED", payload: response.data})

            }
        })
        .catch((err) => {
            dispatch({type: "CREATE_SONG_REJECTED", payload: err})
        })
    }
}
```

I want to be able to return a promise after dispatching so I can use the function like this inside a component -

```
 createSong(title, url, token)
   .then((result) =>{
        // do stuff with result 
     })
```

I know I can pass in a callback to make this work async.. but I want to use ES6 features of promises. And I'm a little confused how I can do this.

Comment: well neither `function (dispatch) {` nor `.then((response) => {` return anything, so that's a problem for a start

Comment: Just return from axios: `return axios.post('http://localhost:8080/api/song/create' ...`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to go full ES6 you should use the `async/await` syntax. This eliminates the need to deal with promises at all.

```
export function createSong (title, url, token) {
  axios.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = token
  return async (dispatch) => {
    try {
      const response = await axios.post('http://localhost:8080/api/song/create', {
        title,
        link: url
      })
      console.log('the response was', response)
      if (response.data.success) {
        dispatch({type: 'CREATE_SONG_FULFILLED', payload: response.data.song})
      } else {
        dispatch({type: 'CREATE_SONG_REJECTED', payload: response.data})
      }
    } catch (err) {
      dispatch({type: 'CREATE_SONG_REJECTED', payload: err})
    }
  }
}
```

The anonymous function returned by `createSong` is marked with the new `async` keyword. This means that the anonymous function will now return an implicit Promise.

The `async` keyword also allows you to use `await` in the body of the function so you can `await` the async call to `axios.post` and so treat it as if it were a synchronous call.

Another advantage is that you can go back to using normal `try / catch` blocks. These are actually resolving and rejecting the implicit promise behind the scenes but they act in the normal way.

Because the anonymous function is actually returning a Promise, higher up the call chain, wherever you call the `createSong(...)` function, you can also use the `async / await` syntax ... and so on. No more callbacks, and no more explicit Promise handling.

Comment: This can be accomplished without using `async/await`.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need to return the `axios` call.

```
...
return function (dispatch) {
  return axios.post('http://localhost:8080/api/song/create', {
    title,
    link: url
  })
...
```

Your `createSong` function is returning another function (so it's a *curried* function).

Therefore,

```
createSong(title, url, token)(dispatch)
.then(()=>{
  // something
})
```

looks to me pretty valid.

Answer (score 0):

I think that it isn't very 'React' way to use return values of dispatched actions.

There is a better way how to solve 'complex' situations like this using [Redux Saga](https://github.com/redux-saga/redux-saga), example [here](https://redux-saga.js.org/docs/basics/ErrorHandling.html).

Although, I used returned values by dispatched actions in this way in the past:

```
export const updatePage = (id, batch) => {
  return dispatch => {
    dispatch({
      type: 'UPDATE_PAGE',
      payload: {
        id
      }
    })

    // Make an API call
    return requestUpdatePages(
      id, batch
    ).then(data => {
      // When API call is successful
      return dispatch({
        type: 'UPDATE_PAGE_SUCCESS',
        payload: {
          id,
          data
      })
    })
    .catch(error => {
      // When API call fails
      return dispatch({
        type: 'UPDATE_PAGE_FAIL',
        payload: {
          error,
          id
        },
        error: true
      })
    })
  }
}

// After dispatch is bound to action creators
// you can use it like this

handleClick(id) {
  const { updatePage } = this.props
  updatePage(id).then(action => {
    if(action.type === 'UPDATE_PAGE_SUCCESS') {
      console.log('Whee, page has been updated!', action.payload.data)
    } else {
      console.error('Something went wrong :-( ', action.payload.error)
    }
  })
}
```